# using a property of an entity as a choice list

Tags: php, symfony, orm

i'm using symfony2 and sonata admin to manage my entities , for my "Event" entity  i'm configuring Form Fields as follow :

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->add('titre', 'text', array('label' => 'titre'))
        ->add('ville', 'entity', array('class' => 'AgendaBundle\Entity\Ville','property' => 'titre'))
        ->add('isactive')
    ;
}
```

the form is well generated with the list of "ville" entity titles but when i try to add new "Event" i get an sql exception **SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax** 
in the sql syntax generated i see that symfony is trying to insert the "ville" value as an empty array : `An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO event (titre, ville , isActive) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["test", {}, 1]:`

what can be wrong ?

Comment: Can you show us the mapping info for the `Event` entity, specifically `Event::$ville`?

Comment: "ville" is just a text field in "event" entity

Comment: the error is say that 'INSERT INTO event (titre, ville , isActive) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)' you have three field and parameter bind with four values '?'.  Without your clear code it is not possible to identify where is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If `Event::$ville` is just a text/string field, then that's likely to be part of the problem.

The `entity` type fields are going to bind back to the underlying object as an association i.e. a foreign key.

If you want the value of of `Ville::$titre` to end up in `event.ville` then you should just switch to a `choice` field with a custom `choice_list` in the form of your own [EntityChoiceList](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Form/ChoiceList/EntityChoiceList.html), specifically with regards to the implementation of `EntityChoiceList::getValues()`

Comment: This should be foreign key but not must be there. without foreign key we add as entity. And this not the error of this.